# Receiving onLoginCancel from uber android api after correct login

Tags: android, uber-api

I am testing out my app for Android which uses Uber API to login, extracted from the uber api example (pretty much unchanged from the SSO button), and it works as intended for most of my testers and me, on both my sample devices and emulator, but on a couple of devices I am getting my "onLoginCancel" called after the login process successfully completes.

The user clicks on sign on, the uber app appears to open and then proceeds to ask for permission, when the user clicks to allow the app, it returns to my login screen with the user cancelled message. There is no message on my debug log pointing to this issue (other then a "Login Cancelled" one), and no errors appear to occur. I am having a hard time finding out what is happening since I am not getting an error message with the failed attempt, is there any way to get an error message out of this situation? Any ideas as to what could be causing the problem?

Both devices that are having this issue are samsungs, one a tablet (the tester couldn`t say exactly which tablet) and one a Samsung Galaxy Ace 4 Lite Duos SM-G313M, both devices have Android version 4.4.2.

EDIT: To better show what I am doing, I will place bellow a resumed version of my app code with only the login stuff. The login screen is just a normal screen showing a button that uses SSO with uber.

```
public static final String CLIENT_ID = BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID;
public static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8000";
private static final String LOG_TAG = "LoginActivity";
private static final int CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE = 1113;

private Button customButton;
private AccessTokenManager accessTokenManager;
private LoginManager loginManager;
private SessionConfiguration configuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            // same issue with PRODUCTION environment
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX) 
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS))
            .build();

    validateConfiguration(configuration);

    accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(this);

    //Use a custom button with an onClickListener to call the LoginManager directly
    loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager,
            new MyLoginCallback(),
            configuration,
            CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE);

    customButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_uber_button);
    customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginManager.login(LoginActivity.this);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("onActivityResult requestCode:[%s] resultCode [%s]",
            requestCode, resultCode));

    if (requestCode == CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE) {
        //Allow each a chance to catch it.
        loginManager.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private class MyLoginCallback implements LoginCallback {

    @Override
    public void onLoginCancel() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Login cancel");
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.user_cancels_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Login error: " + error.name());
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                getString(R.string.login_error_message, error.name()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Main.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
    }
}

/**
 * Validates the local variables needed by the Uber SDK used in the sample project
 * @param configuration
 */
private void validateConfiguration(SessionConfiguration configuration) {
    String nullError = "%s can't be empty";
    String sampleError = "Please update your %s in the gradle.properties of the project before " +
            "using the Uber SDK Sample app. For a more secure storage location, " +
            "please investigate storing in your user home gradle.properties ";

    checkNotNull(configuration, String.format(nullError, "SessionConfiguration"));
    checkNotNull(configuration.getClientId(), String.format(nullError, "Client ID"));
    checkNotNull(configuration.getRedirectUri(), String.format(nullError, "Redirect URI"));
    checkState(!configuration.getClientId().equals("insert_your_client_id_here"),
            String.format(sampleError, "Client ID"));
    checkState(!configuration.getRedirectUri().equals("insert_your_redirect_uri_here"),
            String.format(sampleError, "Redirect URI"));
}
```

Upon running the app, these are the only logs I get, no error or anything:

```
03-21 13:32:19.788 5035-5035/com.mycomp.myapp I/LoginActivity: onActivityResult requestCode:[1113] resultCode [0]
03-21 13:32:19.838 5035-5035/com.mycomp.myapp D/LoginActivity: Login cancel
```

Comment: Can you provide more details and the exact device/app version? I am not able to duplicate this issue with the information provided.

Comment: I've gotten hold of the Galaxy Ace, the Uber app version is v4.144.11. The login works on the uber app, the tester that reported the incident even uses this device to requests uber rides frequently, the problem occurs when logging in on my app. I've uploaded a video showing the issue happening: [video link](https://youtu.be/Uh7oxd6Vz4s)

Comment: Oh, forgot to say, if the app being in portuguese is an issue let me know and I'll make one in english, but basically that last toast just says "User cancelled the login" and returned the user to the login start, instead of proceeding with my app as expected.

Comment: Just had a new tester report the same issue on a Galaxy gt-s5310c, also running android 4.4.2.

Comment: I have just updated the apps uber rides sdk to version 0.6.0 (the latest), and the issue persists on both production and sandbox environments. Do you need any further info?

Comment: To anyone with this same issue, the only thing I could do was limit my app to API level 20+ for now, hopefully this issue will grab someones attention at one point. I also reverted to uber sdk 0.5.4, as 0.6.0 introduced issues that broke my application.